# How exactly batching works in Microsoft sync framework

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Let's say i am uploading large amount of data, which leads to 1000 Batches.
after 500 batches the connection is broken. will i be able to see the changes to corresponding to these 500 change batches.

or, they will be enabled only when the whole 1000 batches are downloaded after the connection is reestablished.

Answer (score 0):

batches are applied in a single transaction. so you should not be seeing partial synchs.